# SQL Server 2008 FTS CONTAINSTABLE Not Returning More Than Five Rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a single table called "Indexes", it contains one nvarchar and three ntext columns (all Full Text Indexes). Index is up to date.

```
CONTAINSTABLE(Indexes, *), 'test', 5) //5 results
```

No matter what I change the above keyword too, it only returns the first 3-5 results. It should roughly return 90-120 results, for the above query.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Indexes WHERE [Description] like '%test%' //122 results
```

How would I start to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`CONTAINSTABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760(SQL.105).aspx) has the `top_n_by_rank` parameter set to 5

You'll never get more then 5 rows with this... the comment `//5 results` even mentions it..

You should use `CONTAINSTABLE(Indexes, *), 'test')`

Comment: Yep indeed that was the solution, I kept thinking 5 was the stopword list